# change app name in expo for iOS builds on Apple

Tags: ios, expo, eas, expo-build

when running `eas build` I get the error below. Does anyone know how to change the name in the CLI the docs don't explain this and all I've found while searching is [this article](https://benborgers.com/posts/expo-app-name) which explains how to do it with expo cli, but not eas cli.

```
 Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
√ Apple ID: ... xxer@XXXXXX.com
› Restoring session C:\Users\jonat\.app-store\auth\xxxxx@xxxxxx.com\cookie
› Team xxxx Limited Liability Company (xxxxxx)
› Provider xxxx Limited Liability Company (xxxx)
√ Logged in Local session

✔ Bundle identifier registered com.XXXXXX
✖ Failed to create App Store app XXXXXXX
App name "xxxxx" has already been used on a different account. If you have trademark rights to this name and would like it released for your use, submit a claim to Apple.
Visit https://appstoreconnect.apple.com and resolve any warnings, then try again.
    Error: Submission failed
PS C:\Users\jonat\XXXXXX\mobile>
```

Answer (score -1):

**How to change the already logged-in username and password of expo app?**

use this command in the terminal->

```
expo login
```

it will ask y/n.
press y
and then enter new username and password.